# Google maps markers z index on top of infobox

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps

is there a way to make google maps markers be on top of infoboxes?

Can't seem to find a solution...

Comment: Do you mean InfoWindow? So you want markers on the map to display on top of InfoWindows? That's poor design and counter-intuitive for the user. If you don't want InfoWindows hiding any markers, consider using semi-transparent InfoWindows instead.

Comment: infoboxes are like more styled info windows. The reason i want them behind the markers is that (since it's a highly styled app) the custom markers would appear to be resting on top of infoboxes styled as sheets of paper. you get what i mean? just imagine having a lego man (marker) standing on top of a post it (infobox). http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can make transparent `InfoBubble`s, with `rgba` colors. It's probably the easiest workaround. The content is any HTML string so you should be able to apply CSS styles, as shown in the examples.

```
 infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
      map: map,
      content: '<div class="phoneytext">Some label</div>',
      ...
```

The InfoBubble page: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html?compiled

**My DEMO** http://www.tinabama.com/googlemaps/1.html

```
    infoBubble2 = new InfoBubble({
      map: map,
      content: 'some text<br>more text<br><br>more more text',
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(44.2, -74),
      shadowStyle: 1,
      padding: 0,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(57,57,57,0.3)',
      borderRadius: 4,
      arrowSize: 10,
      borderWidth: 1,
      borderColor: '#2c2c2c',
      disableAutoPan: true,
      hideCloseButton: true,
      arrowPosition: 30,
      backgroundClassName: 'phoney',
      arrowStyle: 2
    });

    infoBubble2.open();
```